# How does one downgrade TextMate Bundles?

Tags: textmate

Today I lost many hours of work trying to recover from a recent update to various TextMate Bundles that broke my TextMate installation (I had TextMate set to automatically update bundles, am using the current nightly build TextMate 2.0-alpha.9547 and recent changes asked /usr/bin/env for ruby18, which it didn't know).

So the question arises: Is there an "easy" way to downgrade TextMate Bundles to previous revisions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also running Textmate 2.0 alpha.9547 so am quite interested in hearing which of the bundle updates caused the problem!

But to your problem, one simple way would be to restore the offending bundle from your backups.

On my system I find the bundles in:

```
/Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles
```

The harder method would be to locate the download site for the bundle and grab an older copy.  The textmate bundle repository is at: https://github.com/textmate/

To find a particular bundle, just append the bundle name, including the file extension to this path.  For example, the TODO bundle source is at https://github.com/textmate/TODO.tmbundle

From there you would need to clone the git repository and then use git commands to checkout the older version of the source.

I do see that there appears to be a global change to add a "ruby1.8 shim" 6 days ago and bundles have been modified as you noted. I did some quick checking and I appear to be running with the same modifications and as far as I can tell so far, the bundles are working OK.

(would have done this as a comment to the question but I don't have quite enough reputation yet.  ;)

Comment: Indeed my issue was the "ruby 1.8 shim"; since I had modified my PATH inside TextMate (and forgot to prepend `$PATH:`) it was unable to find ruby18. Since I had modified my PATH ages ago, I didn't relate that to my issues and it took me quite some while to fix it. ;-) Maybe there would be a way to downgrade Bundles with git inside the TextMath bundle path?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but not by default.  The Bundle directory is not setup as a git repository so you would need to do that first.  And after a bundle updated through TextMate, you would probably lose the git configuration.  Sounds like you got your problem resolved though by fixing the PATH variable?

Comment: Yeah, the specific problem is fixed now, see github discussion [here](https://github.com/textmate/python.tmbundle/commit/2130a99c262628909c6f8c46a5a03d7dd7e98e13) I'll just wait a few more days to see whether there is a more comfortable fix than going through TimeMachine to downgrade bundles, then I'll accept your answer ;-)

Comment: There is a blog post about the ruby18 problem http://blog.macromates.com/2014/defining-a-path/